# Geospatial index in MongoDB makes no difference to performance

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to find which documents are geo-located within a given rectangle. I have a Mongo collection looking a bit like:

```
{
    ...
    "metadata" : {
        ...
        "geometry" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ -0.000, 51.477 ] }
    }
}
```

And my query looks like:

```
db.my_coll.find({ "$query" : { 
                    "metadata.geometry" : { 
                        "$geoIntersects" : { 
                            "$geometry" : { "type" : "Polygon", "coordinates" : [ [ [..., ...], ... ] ] }
} } }, "$explain":1})
```

With no geospatial index I get:

```
{
"cursor" : "BasicCursor",
"isMultiKey" : false,
"n" : 646,
"nscannedObjects" : 19539,
"nscanned" : 19539,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 19539,
"nscannedAllPlans" : 19539,
"scanAndOrder" : false,
"indexOnly" : false,
"nYields" : 152,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"millis" : 125,
...
```

With the geospatial index `db.my_coll.ensureIndex({"metadata.geometry" : "2dsphere"});` I get:

```
{
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor metadata.geometry_2dsphere",
"isMultiKey" : false,
"n" : 646,
"nscannedObjects" : 18726,
"nscanned" : 18727,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 18726,
"nscannedAllPlans" : 18727,
"scanAndOrder" : false,
"indexOnly" : false,
"nYields" : 146,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"millis" : 161,
...
```

i.e.it's *slower* with the index when explaining. Querying from an outside application shows no significant difference in query time with or without the index (ms resolution). What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't the index make the query rather faster than this?

Thanks :-)

Comment: Don't rely on the `ms` field as meaning very much in an explain. The `n`, `nscanned`, `nscannedObjects` are more meaningful...except their interpretation is more complicated with a geospatial index than a normal one. I'd say it might just be that your not going to see a significant speedup, or even may see a small slowdown, for this geo query on this pretty small data size. If you scale up the number of documents, does the performance of the geoquery relative to the collection scan improve?